# LINQ query help: searching for data in a Many to Many using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I've poked around and seen a bunch of similar questions, but I still can't figure this out. I've got two classes Assets and Tags. Here are their definitions:

```
public class Asset
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetID { get; set; }

    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public decimal? Width { get; set; }
    public decimal? Depth { get; set; }
    public decimal? Radius { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public int PackageTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual PackageType PackageType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

}
```

I've got a search box on my Asset Index page and I want to be able to search for Asset.Name, Manufacturer.Name, Asset.Tag.Key, and Asset.Tag.Value. Here's what I've got so far.

```
var assets = from a in db.Assets                        
                     select a;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
assets = assets.Where(a => a.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
          || a.Manufacturer.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
}
```

Now, I have no idea how the heck to access/search for The Tag.Key or Tag.Value. I've tried all sorts of joins with the LINQ query, but I'm just not smart enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Any to check the Tags and filter by searchString

```
var result = db.Assets.Where(a => a.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                                  a.Manufacturer.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||                       
                                  a.Tags.Any(t => t.Key.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || t.Value.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: Fixed, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to make a search "case insensitive", you change the [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx) of your database table columns.

Then, your LINQ code:

```
var assets = db.Assets.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(searchString)
      || a.Manufacturer.Name.Contains(searchString)
      || a.Tags.Any(t => t.Key == searchString || t.Value == searchString));
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about collation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.Any()` extension method to find if the asset contains a tag with the defined search term

```
var result = db.Assets.Where(a => a.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                               || a.Manufacturer.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()
                               || a.Tags.Any(t => t.Key == searchString)
                               || a.Tags.Any(t => t.Value == searchString)
```